# unable to write csv file, python

Tags: python, csv

here is my code, i added exception to indexerror, but its not writing to csv file.

```
import urllib2
import csv
import time
import requests
import os

#a = open(r"C:\Drive F data\Client\Blake\III\2.txt")
a = ['http://www.houzz.com/trk/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5SSUtCLmNvbQ/b020157b98711b4a190eee3331eb0066/ue/MjA5ODg2MQ/1b9b00b9fdc9f270f14688046ef161e2',
    'http://www.houzz.com/trk/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nc2NhYmluZXRyeS5jb20/0323b7db059b9e0357d045685be21a6d/ue/NDY2MjE0/d8815293352eb2a6e40c95060c019697',
    'http://www.houzz.com/trk/aHR0cDovL3NpY29yYS5jb20/dc807b3705b95b5da772a7aefe23a803/ue/Njc0NDA4/a73f8bdb38e10abd5899fb5c55ff3548',
    'http://www.houzz.com/trk/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5DYXNlRGVzaWduLmNvbQ/d79c6af934e3c815d602c4d79b0d6617/ue/OTY3MDg/ce9a87e31e84871a96bca7538aae9856',
    'http://www.houzz.com/trk/aHR0cDovL2phcnJldHRkZXNpZ25sbGMuY29t/9d0009d3544d9c22f6058b20097321b3/ue/MzExNTk1NA/310d49732d317725364368ea3fbfd7c1',
    'http://www.houzz.com/trk/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5yb2JlcnRsZWdlcmVkZXNpZ24uY29t/8ac7311be2f794654cefba71474563f7/ue/MTExNTQ4/af201ffdc62de6aba9e2de90f69a770d']

with open("C:\Drive F data\Blake\III/2.csv", "ab")as export:
    names = ['source','link']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(export, fieldnames=names)
    writer.writeheader()
    for each in a:
        try:
            link = urllib2.urlopen(each).geturl()
        except IndexError:
            pass
        print each, link
        writer.writerow({'source':each,'link':link})
```

After removing try & exception , it works fine

Comment: "C:\\Drive F data\\Blake\\III/2.csv" ?

Comment: replace pass in except block with print(IndexError) and post the printed exception

Comment: got it working right, it was bad Pycharm community edition i was trying but working excellent from terminal. Thank guys

Comment: Is there a way , i can resume next on error. with pass it quits & stops,

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss escape character in your file path. `"C:\\Drive F data\\Blake\\III\\2.csv"`

Comment: no that is not the problem, when i remove try exception , it works fine, i think i am dong something wrong with exception part

Comment: I see the code you comment out is slightly different `#a = open(r"C:\Drive F data\Client\Blake\III\2.txt")` from the `open` you use. you may try again to put `r` before the string. But it's just another way to fix the same problem here.